# Not able to open "ssh://192.168.1.120" in browser using php script

Tags: php, html, ssh

There is firessh add-on for mozilla to support ssh client service. We have to enter url such as "ssh://192.168.1.120" in browser to open firessh service. But i need to open that url in browser through php script on click of html button. My php script can open 'Location http://192.168.1.120". But it cannot open ssh://192.168.1.120 in browser through php script(when html button is clicked)

Comment: Without code we would only be guessing.

Comment: It is no mentioned on the http://firessh.net/help.html page. Please provide your html code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all ensure that Firefox correctly handles `SSH://` requests.

Then return the following HTML page from your PHP script:

```
<?php 

    // Do some PHP stuff here

?>

<html>
    <head>
       <script>
          window.location.href="ssh://192.168.1.120";</script>
       </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

You should be redirected to the `ssh` plugin as soon as the page loads.